# Uploading Multiple APK in playstore - update is not pushed from playstore to device

Tags: android, google-play

I have successfully uploaded 2 apk in playstore in advance mode.

1. In Feb 2016 - uploaded app with version 1.1 & version code 2 & supporting API 9+.
2. Today added one more apk to support only mobile and API 23 with version 2.0 & version code 3.
3. Added in advance mode and both app version is in prod status in playstore.
4. After 6 hours - One device running Android 6.0 had existing app in it when checking for update in playstore it still shows 1.1 version only.
5. checking on another device running Android 6.0 where it is fresh install of the same app shows version 2.0 app in playstore.

Problem is existing app installed on Android 6.0 device is not getting update from playstore. SO does it take more time to get update when submitting multiple apk?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

> So does it take more time to get update when submitting multiple apk?

It shouldn't take longer than usual but note that the APK itself might take longer than 6 hours to become available to all devices. In my experience, you frequently have to wait close to 24 hours before all devices start seeing it. In addition to that, remember that some devices have restrictions around when/how to check for updates (e.g. being on Wi-fi vs Mobile Data, checking no more than once every N hours, etc), so I'd be patient and give it time.

You should also check if the two devices are exactly the same. If, for example, your new APK includes native code but is missing the native libraries for your device's platform, or specifies screen/hardware capabilities that your new device is missing then the Play Store will continue to offer the old APK on that device.

Comment: Thanks Mike!! App does not have any device specific feature. As you said I just verified on 2 samsung devices running 6.0.1 and its first time installation of the app. It seems the playstore is showing version 1.1 of the app. So I will wait for 24hrs then to see the update or new app available.